# Знаки препинания в моем предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Проверьте, пожалуйста, знаки препинания.

> Так, приводя в своём тексте немало, казалось бы, синонимичных выражений, обозначающих ту самую  «жизненную сферу», автор доказывает своё  утверждение: жизнь не имеет границ *(это цитата, нужны ли кавычки?),* тем самым подчёркивая  безграничность человеческих возможностей.

Comment: Вы проверяете собственный текст?

Comment: @shampar, да, свой, мне кажется, что нужны кавычки, но я не уверен ( я не могу комментировать из-за недостатка баллов)

Answer (score 1):

Мой вариант:

**Так, приводя в своём тексте немало, казалось бы, синонимичных выражений, обозначающих ту самую «жизненную сферу», автор доказывает своё утверждение «жизнь не имеет границ», тем самым подчёркивая безграничность человеческих возможностей.**

Пример из Нацкорпуса:

> В общем, всё в организме взаимосвязано нервными волокнами, так что и утверждение "всё от нервов" отчасти не лишено смысла. [Валерия Фейгина. Все болезни от нервов (2003) // «100% здоровья», 2003.01.15]